# Microsoft Word 2016 keeps defaulting back to English (United States)

Tags: microsoft-word, language, input-languages

At the bottom left of Word 2016, I see `English (United States)`.

[image]

If I click on this, and select `English (Australia)`, five seconds later it will revert back to `English (United States)`.

I have deselected `Detect Language Automatically`.

In Control Panel > Region, my Location is set to Australia, and my Format is too:

[image]

I also see:

[image]

How do I ensure `English (Australia)` stays current @ bottom left of Word?

Help appreciated.

Comment: See my article on this subject on the Microsoft site: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language displayed by Word does not behave the same as that displayed by
Windows on the taskbar : It describes the language of the text
*at the current cursor position*.

This means that it will change depending on where you are positioned in the
document.

To set the entire documents to one language, select it all
using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then change the language using the
bottom-left pane.

However, even that is sometimes not enough, as it may not set the language of the
virtual character beyond the last character of the document.
So, if you position to the end of the document via
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, it is possible in some cases that your language
will revert. If your document is one of those where this happens, avoid
bypassing the end of the document.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party, but I had a similar problem and I just discovered what is happening:
When I set my proofing language to Dutch and then typed literally anything, it would immediately revert back the proofing language to English, which was driving me crazy!
Then I discovered that this happens after I accidentally presssed  the Win-key and the space bar at the same time, which changes the keyboard layout. And there are three layouts installed, all for an AZERTY-keyboard, so you wouldn't notice the change:

[image: Screenshot]

So but, when you select "ENG - BEP" no problem at all - You set the proofing language and it sticks with the chosen language. Set it to "ENG", and all hell breaks loose: no matter what proofing language you select in Word, it will always roll back to English... How badly programmed is this?